# Debugging tools and tips for dual execution environment of KRL

Tags: debugging, monitoring, environment, krl

Because of the dual execution environment of KRL, I'm looking for better ways to debug my Kynetx applications.

- What applications can I run on my local computer to help with debugging Kynetx apps that interact with the web domain?
- What web services could I use to help debug applications as my users are using the app?
- What tools can I use to help debug twilio or webhook domain Kynetx applications?
- What tools can I use to monitor the uptime of a web domain Kynetx application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Web domain debugging of KRL events

Using the Firebug Net tab is really great for getting event responses when working in the web domain. You can filter by type, view the event url, and the response from the Kynetx server.

Firebug Net tab showing all resources loaded on stackoverflow.com:

[image]

Firebug Net tab filtering by JavaScript resource:

[image]

Firebug Net tab showing request parameters of pageview event being raised to Kynetx server by bookmarklet:

[image]

You can also view the response which is where the server log will be if logging is turned on in your app.